# query a table with multiple rows for same id, into single data row in results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a few tables like this where a person has multiple data rows. The IDs are sequential but do not always start at 1. Is there a way to have the results come out in a single data row for each person. I have a few tables like this and I ultimately would like to join them via CLIENT_ID, but I'm a bit stumped. Is this possible?

Using oracle sql.

| CLIENT_ID | NAME | ID | ID_DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | joe | 1 | apple |
| 5 | joe | 5 | orange |
| 68 | brian | 2 | orange |
| 68 | brian | 6 | mango |
| 68 | brian | 10 | lemon |
| 12 | katie | 3 | watermelon |

where the results look like this

| CLIENT_ID | NAME | ID1 | ID1_DESCRIPTION | ID2 | ID2_DESCRIPTION | ID3 | ID3_DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | joe | 1 | apple | 5 | orange |  |  |
| 68 | brian | 2 | orange | 6 | mango | 10 | lemon |
| 12 | katie | 3 | watermelon |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Read up on PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

If Pivot ist not available, this should do it:

```
Select
Client_id,
sum(case when id_description='apple' then 1 else 0 end) as Apples,
sum(case when id_description='orange' then 1 else 0 end) as Oranges...
[]etc.
from
t
group by Client_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Might need some minor tweaking as I wrote this just off the top of my head, but something like this should work. Will say this doesn't account for more than 3 rows per `CLIENT_ID`. For that, would need to do a dynamic pivot (plenty of online articles on this topic).

### Pivoting Based on Order of Items

```
WITH cte_RowNum AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
        ,*
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT CLIENT_ID
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN ID END) AS ID1
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN [Description] END) AS ID1_DESCRIPTION
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN ID END) AS ID2
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 2 THEN [Description] END) AS ID2_DESCRIPTION
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN ID END) AS ID3
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN RowNum = 3 THEN [Description] END) AS ID3_DESCRIPTION
FROM cte_RowNum
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID;
```